# How to make onclick events on 3d amcharts version 3 in column chart

Tags: php, graph, amcharts

I am using amcharts version 3 for graph. I want to add click event on this chart. I find alot on Stack and other sites but I could not find any solution. Plz Help Me To resolve my problem.

Here is the Code of the graph Script:

```
<script>

    var chart10;
        var chartData10 = [           
            {
                "allocated": "<?php echo date('F-Y', strtotime('-1 month'));?>",
                "visits": "<?php echo $MONTH4?>",
                "color": "#00A65A"
            },
            {
                "allocated": "<?PHP echo date('F-Y')?>",
                "visits": "<?php echo $MONTH1?>",
                "color": "#FAF603"
            },
            {
                "allocated": "<?php echo date('F-Y' ,strtotime('+1 month', strtotime(date('F-Y'))));?>",
                "visits": <?php echo $MONTH2?>,
                "color": "#0D52D1"
            },
             {
                "allocated": "<?php echo date('F-Y', strtotime('+2 month'));?>",
                "visits": "<?php echo $MONTH3?>",
                "color": "#FF0F00"
            }   
        ];


        AmCharts.ready(function () {
            // SERIAL CHART
            chart10 = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
            chart10.dataProvider = chartData10;
            chart10.categoryField = "allocated";
            chart10.startDuration = 1;
            chart10.depth3D = 20;
            chart10.angle = 20;
            chart10.marginRight = -30;
            // AXES
            // category
            var categoryAxis = chart10.categoryAxis;
            categoryAxis.labelRotation = 45; // this line makes category values to be rotated
            categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0;
            categoryAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
            categoryAxis.color =  'black';
            categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";
            // value
            var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
            valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
            valueAxis.gridAlpha = 0;
            valueAxis.minimum = 0;
            valueAxis.gridColor = "#FFFFFF";
            valueAxis.color =  'black';
            chart10.addValueAxis(valueAxis);
            // GRAPH
            var graph12 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph12.valueField = "visits";
            graph12.colorField = "color";
            graph12.balloonText = "<b>[[allocated]]: [[value]]</b>";
            graph12.type = "column";
            graph12.lineAlpha = 0.2;
            graph12.lineColor = "#FFFFFF";
    graph12.gridColor = "#FFFFFF";
            graph12.topRadius = 1;
            graph12.fillAlphas = 1;
    graph12.color =  '#FFFFFF';
    graph12.labelText =  '[[value]]'; 
    graph12.labelRotation = 0;
    graph12.labelPosition = 'bottom';
            chart10.addGraph(graph12);

            // CURSOR
            var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
            chartCursor.cursorAlpha = 0;
            chartCursor.zoomable = false;
            //chartCursor.categoryBalloonEnabled = true;
           // chartCursor.valueLineEnabled = true;
            chartCursor.valueLineBalloonEnabled = false;
            chartCursor.valueLineAlpha = 0;
            chart10.addChartCursor(chartCursor);
            chart10.creditsPosition = "top";

            // WRITE
            chart10.write("monthprod");
        });



    </script>
```

Where i want to add Click events and how to add in amcharts version 3. Plz help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance.